# Result type of Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I'm making an application with sql database,

I get my data like this:

```
var vAll= from a in vPRCEntities.tblProducts
          select a;
```

which variable is 'vAll' then?, becouse i wanna use that in a methode:

```
private void vGet( ?? vAll)
{
}
```

Comment: IEnumerable of the tblProducts collection type

Comment: how can i write my methode then?
private void vGet(IEnumerable vAll)
that dosn't work.

Comment: @ParysBernard try `private void vGet(IEnumerable<Product> vAll) ` or whatever the type is

Comment: @nawfal - why don't you make your answer an "answer" rather than a "comment"?

Comment: You can usually hover over the "var" and your IDE will tell you what the actual type is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this as suggested:

```
private void vGet(IEnumerable<Product> vAll){ }
```

Keep in mind that Linq uses delayed execution wich means the query won't actually execute until you read from the collection. That is okay but if you read the collection in a different part of the application you might run into issues.  For example, the connection might get closed before you have a chance to get the data.

To avoid this you could try something like this:

```
var vAll = (from a in vPRCEntities.tblProducts select a).ToList<Product>();
```

This forces the collection to be read right away and puts it into a List<> object.  You can then write your method like this:

```
private void vGet(List<Product> vAll){ } //IEnumerable will also work
```

Delayed execution is no longer in play since the collection has been read and put into a list.

Note: if the amount of data is very large then all of that data will be in memory in the list and this might not be a good solution. Like most things - it depends.

Answer (score 0):

I thought its too trivial for an answer. Furthermore the real credit goes to Charleh who pointed out the missing part. Anyway here it is

Try:

```
private void vGet(IEnumerable<Product> vAll)
```

where `Product` has to be your type in `tblProducts` :)